# Datepicker dialog cannot be displayed in android

Tags: android, datepicker

Am trying to get the date using spinner widget. Date gets displayed on the TOAST message but when i click on the spinner datepicker dialog box does not open. cannot find fault.

Here is my code snippet.

Main Actvity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_apply_leave);

    leaveApplyFromDate = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.leaveApplyFromDate);

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    showDate(year, month+1, day);


    leaveApplyFromDate.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), leaveApplyFromDate.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setDate(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });


}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (id == 999) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateListener, year, month, day);
    }
    return null;
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void setDate(View view) {
    showDialog(999);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ca", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // arg1 = year
        // arg2 = month
        // arg3 = day
        showDate(arg1, arg2+1, arg3);
    }
};

private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {
   // leaveApplyFromDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/")
       //     .append(month).append("/").append(year));
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/")
                .append(month).append("/").append(year),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And here is my xml layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.hrm.staff.ApplyLeave">

            <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/leaveApplyFromDate"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:background="@color/spinner_bg_start"
            android:ems="10" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why your spinner in the layout doesn't have a width?

Comment: @OrkunKoçyiğit: coz i have put that into table row and have set weight for it as you can see.

Comment: Your code works for me if the spinner is not empty

Comment: sorry i didn't get you. what does it mean.. spinner is not empty ..?

Comment: I added simple adapter with numbers from 1 to 10 and if I pick some number it works.

Comment: can you tell why its not working without adding adapter. coz here am displaying a dialog box.

Comment: Cause the listener you implemented is onItemSelected, to it to be worked there must be some items which will be getting selected. If you want it to work you can either implement onTouchListener but then you have to change your logic as getSelectedItem will be always null without an adapter or learn to use adapters for your use case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok. now i got the answer.I have changed some of my code and xml also to make it work. hope this will help other too. Am posting here the code that is working

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_apply_leave);

leaveApplyFromDate = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.leaveApplyFromDate);

calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
showDate(year, month+1, day);

 setDate(); // calling this function to fetch the date before it is clicked

 /* applying onlicklistener to textview of the date to open the date dialog box */ 
 leaveApplyFromDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setDateDialog(); // calling this function to display date dialog box

        }

    });
leaveApplyFromDate.setText(fromDate); // setting date for textview on loading the app

}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (id == 999) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(ApplyLeave.this, myDateListener, year, month, day);
    }
    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void setDate() {


}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void setDateDialog() {
    showDialog(999);

}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // arg1 = year
        // arg2 = month
        // arg3 = day
        showDate(arg1, arg2 + 1, arg3);
        leaveApplyFromDate.setText(fromDate); // setting date for textview after selecting it from date widget.
    }
};

private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {

    StringBuilder date = new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/")
            .append(month).append("/").append(year);
    fromDate = date.toString();

}
```

And this is my Xml layout.

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/leaveApplyFromDate"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_file"
            android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize" />
```

Hope this might help someone.
All the best.

Answer (score 0):

You should call showDialog(999) somewhere in your activity

Comment: its called in setDate(view) function.

Comment: does the toast shows when clicking an item on spinner?

Comment: it displays at the begining but nothing happens when i click spinner.